# How to get name of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
var myobj =
{
test1 : {name1 : "" , name2 : ""},
test2 : {name1 : "" , name2 : ""},
test3 : {name1 : "" , name2 : ""}
}

console.log(myobj) , response ===> Object {test1: Object, test2: Object, test3: Object}
```

How to get name of object... I want this to be the

```
response === > myobj (name of objet)
```

This is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Objects don't have names. What you have there in (say) `test1` is a *property* with a name, whose value is an object reference.

You can loop through the enumerable property names of an object using `for-in` or a `Object.keys(myobj).forEach` loop:

```
var name;
for (name in myobj) {
    console.log(name + ".name1 = " + myobj[name].name1);
}
```

or

```
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + ".name1 = " + myobj[name].name1);
});
```

`for-in` live example:

```js
var myobj =  {
  test1 : {name1 : "Joe" , name2 : ""},
  test2 : {name1 : "Linda" , name2 : ""},
  test3 : {name1 : "Pashtel" , name2 : ""}
};
var name;
for (name in myobj) {
  console.log(name + ".name1 = " + myobj[name].name1);
}
```

`Object.keys(...).forEach` live example:

```js
var myobj =  {
  test1 : {name1 : "Joe" , name2 : ""},
  test2 : {name1 : "Linda" , name2 : ""},
  test3 : {name1 : "Pashtel" , name2 : ""}
};
Object.keys(myobj).forEach(function(name) {
  console.log(name + ".name1 = " + myobj[name].name1);
});
```